# How to put some space between the div and the bottom of body?

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to put a div in the middle of my body. The min height of this div is 400px but the size of this div may increase with content. As I put more content to this div it grows fine but it also start touching the bottom of the div.

I want to have a min space between the div and bottom, so that if the div grows in size atleast that much amount of space is retained between body and div.

My Html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>TODO-List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="StyleSheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
        This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
        This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Css

```
.container
{
    /*display*/
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 40%;

    /*Border*/
    border: 2px solid Grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px Grey;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px Grey;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px Grey;

    /*Position*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    top: 270px;   
}
```

[Here is my code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apoorvasahay/HwpVR/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use absolute positioning, because the body gets a height of 0px. In your case `margin` is the best option.

*Update: now supports auto-centering, so you can change the size as you want, without changing the `margin`*

```
.container
{
    /*display*/
    margin: 270px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 400px;
    width: 40%;

    /*Border*/
    border: 2px solid Grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px Grey;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px Grey;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px Grey;

    /*Position*/
    position: relative; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HwpVR/8/

---

In case you don't understand `margin: 270px auto;`. It will translate to this:

```
margin-top: 270px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 270px;
margin-left: auto;
```

It's the same as `margin: 270px auto 270px auto;`

Answer (score 1):

Do not set position absolute.
For centering content use something like this:

```
margin:0px auto;
width: 1000px;
position: relative;
```

Then you can add some div to add space at the bottom or just set margin-bottom to the content div.

Comment: `position: relative` is not a good option, because it does the same as `posotion: absolute` it removes the block-element from the "noraml flow". That means the parent of that tag will get a height of 0px.

Comment: I do not agree with you on this, this is the preferred way of centering content. Parent of the tag is body and it does not get height of 0px, try it.

Comment: But totally agree with that comment. You're right. I tested it before and I thought `relative` will do the same as `absolute` to the parent.

Comment: The only negative point in your answer is your last sentence. Empty elements are always a bad idea.

Comment: You are right empty element is dirty solution should be avoided.